# Unable to connect my DNS with .app extension to my apache server

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, dns, virtualhost

I am trying to connect my DNS(with .app TLD) to apache server running on EC-2 instance port 80. But it's not connecting, where as DNS(with .in or .com TLD) are connecting easily.Here is my Virtual host config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName xyz.app
        ServerAlias www.xyz.app
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/       

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: "But it's not connecting," The browser was probably giving you a clear explanation of that, and in any case when asking questions it helps a lot if you provide specific detailed errors you see, without rephrasing. Of course you can run your webserver on port 80 there will be no problems there but as Dusan replied browsers will just not connect to that port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [.app](https://blog.google/technology/developers/introducing-app-more-secure-home-apps-web/) top-level domain is included on the HSTS preload list, making HTTPS required on all connections to .app websites — no individual HSTS registration or configuration required. You have to configure apache virtual host to serve traffic over https (port 443)

Comment: And when you buy a `.APP` domain, the registrar is required by the registry to clearly show a message to the prospective registrant explaining to him that his future .APP domain will not work without an SSL(sic) certificate. Also, all others TLDs by Google Registry are in the same boat: `.DEV` for example. Future ones like `.NEW` will be also in same boat.

Comment: Actually I didn't purchase it, but I was expecting this reason. Thanks for making me sure.